# Mobile Device Center does not launch on connecting phone

Tags: windows-8, usb, mobile-phone

I have an HTC mobile phone running WinMobile 6.5.
When I plug it into my laptop (USB connection) which is running Windows 8, the OS recognises that a device has been connected but does not launch Windows Mobile Device Center to connect to the phone.

The phone appears in Device manager with the correct Make/Model, under Portable Devices as well as Mobile Devices, but does not appear in 'Control Panel/Autoplay' under Devices or anything else.

Anyone any ideas how to fix this?